# How do I query artifactory for artifacts that are missing a property

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I have a process I want to run to add some arbitrary property to artifacts that meet a certain criteria but do not already have the property assigned. I tried querying like:

```
items.find({
  "$and":[
    {"repo": "libs-release-local"},
    {"@foo": {"$eq":null}}
  ]

}).include("path", "name")
```

but that never returns any results. Is there some way to query for items that do not have a "foo" property?

Answer (score 3):

I've been successful using a query like:

```
items.find({
  "$and":[
    {"repo": "libs-release-local"},
    {"@foo": {"$nmatch":"*"}}
  ]

}).include("path", "name")
```

Would appreciate if someone with more aql experience can confirm this is the best way to do this and I haven't violated some API and just getting lucky. It was not intuitive at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, using your example:

```
items.find({
  "repo": "libs-release-local",
  "property.key": {"$ne": "foo"}
}).include("path", "name")
```